# I'm receiving an SSL error in various browsers, but I can't find non-SSL content

Tags: ssl, https

I'm receiving an error with my SSL connection. Using google chrome I see the following error:

> Your connection is encrypted with
>   128-bit encryption ... however this
>   page includes other resources which
>   are not secure

I've scoured the source code, scripts and rendered code in the browser but cannot find where an http:// call is made. I've also used Fiddler2 to examine the traffic and everything is coming across via HTTPS. Has anyone run into this issue before and if so how did you go about finding the culprit.

The website is running ASP.NET MVC3 in C#. The page in question is a simple payment page. The only external call is the google analytics tracking code. The page appears to load correctly, all images and scripts are in place.

Comment: I had a similar issue with a page that used the google mapping API.  Without more info on what you've got going on on that page I can't really come up with anything more concrete, though.

Comment: I'll tack on a bit more info

Comment: Maybe one of the HTTPS sessions is using a silly algorithm like DES or 64-bit RC4, neither of which I would call "secure" these days.

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> in Chrome and go to the network tab. In here it should show everything that passes through the browser, and will be a much better way of doing it than looking at the source code, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Facebook badge, which under certain circumstances (I was logged in as a corporate page, not as a user) internally executed some javascript which accessed non-secure content. I discovered this only accidentally. When looking for solution I asked [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/13107/firefox-reports-https-page-to-contain-non-secure-elements) and got some useful answers (well, by that time I've discovered the solution but maybe they will help you).

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause is where an element (e.g an image) is being linked into the page and the link uses http instead of https

A good explanation can be found here.

http://ithemes.com/codex/page/Fix_Non-SSL_Elements_on_SSL_Page

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTTPS Switch Planner from the HTTPS everywhere addon. After you installed it, press CTRL+SHIFT+J and click on the HTTPS Switch Planner tab. There will be a list of resources that are loaded over HTTP.